# OverflowError in cartopy

Tags: python, shapely, cartopy

I'm using cartopy to draw some maps.  In some situations, when calling `.set_extent()` on my axes, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#315>", line 1, in <module>
    ax.set_extent([bounds.X1.min(), bounds.X2.max(), bounds.Y1.min(), bounds.Y2.max()], cartopy.crs.AlbersEqualArea())
  File "C:\FakeProgs\Python27\lib\site-packages\cartopy\mpl\geoaxes.py", line 587, in set_extent
    projected = self.projection.project_geometry(domain_in_crs, crs)
  File "C:\FakeProgs\Python27\lib\site-packages\cartopy\crs.py", line 172, in project_geometry
    return getattr(self, method_name)(geometry, src_crs)
  File "C:\FakeProgs\Python27\lib\site-packages\cartopy\crs.py", line 178, in _project_line_string
    return cartopy.trace.project_linear(geometry, src_crs, self)
  File "lib\cartopy\trace.pyx", line 109, in cartopy.trace.project_linear (lib/cartopy\trace.cpp:1135)
  File "lib\cartopy\trace.pyx", line 71, in cartopy.trace.geos_from_shapely (lib/cartopy\trace.cpp:838)
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

The thing is that the behavior is somewhat random.  Not every call to `.set_extent()` does it.  Here's an excerpt from one interpreter session (`bounds` is a pandas DataFrame holding coordinates of bounding boxes for various shapes that I intend to later add to the axes).

```
>>> ax = pyplot.axes(projection=cartopy.crs.AlbersEqualArea())
... ax.set_extent([bounds.X1.min(), bounds.X2.max(), bounds.Y1.min(), bounds.Y2.max()], cartopy.crs.AlbersEqualArea())
# result is exception shown above
>>> [bounds.X1.min(), bounds.X2.max(), bounds.Y1.min(), bounds.Y2.max()]
[-2218681.0391451684,
 -2103178.2838086924,
 -195096.93292225525,
 7468.2970529943705]
>>> [int(x) for x in [bounds.X1.min(), bounds.X2.max(), bounds.Y1.min(), bounds.Y2.max()]]
[-2218681, -2103178, -195096, 7468]
>>> [long(x) for x in [bounds.X1.min(), bounds.X2.max(), bounds.Y1.min(), bounds.Y2.max()]]
[-2218681L, -2103178L, -195096L, 7468L]
>>> ax = pyplot.axes(projection=cartopy.crs.AlbersEqualArea())
... ax.set_extent([bounds.X1.min(), bounds.X2.max(), bounds.Y1.min(), bounds.Y2.max()], cartopy.crs.AlbersEqualArea())
# works without problem!
```

The same code worked, without changing any of the variables in between.

The error appears to be raised by this line in `trace,pyx`:

```
cdef ptr geos_geom = shapely_geom._geom
```

I did some searching and found [an old commit](https://github.com/olt/shapely/commit/5cce26429a80f1ff944b5deb1e9095df3eba3188) related to a similar issue that was raised on [some mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/imposm/QWEKSw-zBJA/CqFb1faijZwJ).

My understanding of the problem is that the `_geom` attribute of these Shapely objects stores some sort of pointer to an object in some C library.  If this pointer's integer value is too big for a C long, the error is raised.  The error is not reproducible because a new `_geom` is created every time I create a new `GeoAxes`, and the new `_geom` may or may not be too big.

One puzzling thing, though, is that most of what I can find about this error (for instance, the commit message on the above commit) suggests it should only be a problem for 32-bit systems, but I'm using 64-bit Python 2.7 with 64-bit versions of all libraries.

So my question is: am I right about what is going on?  If so, why am I still getting these errors on a 64-bit system?  And is there a way to work around it?

Answer (score 1):

> am I right about what is going on?

I can't confirm categorically that you are right, but it certainly looks plausible. I've never seen the problem before, but equally I don't tend to use cartopy on Windows on a regular basis.

> If so, why am I still getting these errors on a 64-bit system?

Your machine might be 64-bit, but is the Python you are using 64-bit?

> And is there a way to work around it?

Given it seems random, the workaround might be to do:

```
for attempt in range(10):
    try:
        ...
    except OverflowError:
        print('Failed attempt {}, retrying upto 10 times.'.format(attempt))
```

It certainly isn't pretty, but may be the only way to workaround at this point.

Clearly what you are finding is a bug, so I think the [cartopy issue tracker](https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/issues/new) is the right place to find a long-term solution to the problem. I think it would be a good idea to provide the versions of the software you are using, and ideally the coordinates which you are finding trigger the problem (even if randomly).

HTH

Comment: Yes, I'm using 64-bit Python.  I'll raise an issue on the tracker.